# Интересно мнение экспертов. Java ООП

Tags: java, ооп, инспекция-кода

Интересно мнение экспертов. Программа угадывает задуманное число, и пишет за скольо ходов она его угадала.

**Класс Main**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GuessingConsoleGame game = new GuessingConsoleGame();
        game.Start();
    }
}
```

**Класс GuessingConsoleGame**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingConsoleGame {
    public void Start() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        GuessingBinary guessing = new GuessingBinary();

        System.out.println("Guessing game number");
        System.out.println("If we guessed your num - press [y]" +
                "\nIf your number bigger than proposed by us - press [>]" +
                "\nIf your number less than proposed us - press [<]");

        System.out.print("Enter min border: ");
        int min = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter max border: ");
        int max = scanner.nextInt();

        while (max < min) {
            System.out.println("Max can't be less than min. Try again");
            System.out.print("Enter max border: ");
            max = scanner.nextInt();
        }

        guessing.initialization(min, max);

        while (!guessing.isTrue()) {
            System.out.println("Attempt: " + guessing.getCount());
            System.out.println("Your num is: " + guessing.getGuessedNum());
            System.out.print(":");
            guessing.guessing(scanner.next());
        }
    }
}
```

**Класс GuessingBinary**

```
public class GuessingBinary {
private int min, max;
    private int count;
    private int guessedNum;
    private boolean isTrue;
    private int half;

    public void initialization(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        isTrue = false;
        count = 1;
        half = max / 2;
        guessedNum = half;
    }

    public int getGuessedNum() {
        return guessedNum;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public boolean isTrue() {
        return isTrue;
    }

    public void guessing(String string) {
        if (string.equals("y")) {
            isTrue = true;
        } else if (string.equals("<")) {
            max = half;
        } else if (string.equals(">")) {
            min = half;
        }
        half = ((max - min) / 2) + min;
        count++;
        guessedNum = half;
    }
}
```

Comment: Работает? Не трогай!

Answer (score 3):

1. Несоблюдение [Java Naming Convention](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367), например режет глаз `Start()` с заглавной буквы. Название класса `GuessingBinary` тоже вызывает вопросы
2. `GuessingBinary.initialization()` - вынести в конструктор
3. Методу `guessing()` надо возвращать сразу `boolean`

Answer (score 2):

Когда вы пишете код, каждая ваша строчка должна иметь смысл. Каждый класс должен иметь причину, почему он существует и почему он написан именно так, как написан.

Вот что у вас за задача? Игра в угадайку. У вас есть класс `GuessingBinary` назначение которого - угадывать число, используюя двоичный поиск. Почему вдруг этот класс стал хранить состояние игры? Почему этот класс стал решать, угадал он или нет? Почему этот класс стал вести подсчет попыток угадываний?

Окей, давайте я вам поясню самый главный принцип программирования. Вы можете думать о нем как о принципе "разделяй и влавствуй". При построении сложной системы сегодня программист просто не в силах справиться со сложностью всей системы разом. Поэтому сложные системы разбивают на модули, модули на классы, классы на методы и данные. То есть в конечном итоге сложная система - это взаимодействие простых классов. И чем проще написан класс, тем меньше шанс запутаться.

Но как определить, достаточно и просто написан класс? Достаточно ли он гибкий, чтобы его переиспользовать? Четких универсальных ответов нет на это, но есть рекомендации. Паттерны, принципы, практики - это рекомендации, как сделать ваш класс или что вы пишете простым, но при этом составить из таких классов что то сложное.

Возьмем например, принцип единственности ответсвенности. Вот зачем он нужен? Зачем я вам про него писал в вашем предыдущем вопросе? Вот для того, чтобы вы, когда написали класс, задумались - а достаточно ли он простой? А можно ли его разбить на несколько классов? А зачем бы это делать?  - чтобы понять это, вы определяете, какие у класса есть ответсвенности, как они связаны с его назначением.

Вот у вас класс `GuessingBinary`. Его назначение - угадывать. Не хранить верные ответы. Не оределять, когда он угадал или не угадал. Не интерпретировать ввод от пользователя. Нет. Только угадывать.

Что ему нужно, чтобы произвести угадывание? Чтобы произвести угадывание единоразово, ему нужно хнать только 2 вещи - минимум и максимум. Все. Больше для угадывания этому классу знать не надо ничего.

Но как передатьь классу эти минимум и максимум? У нас есть 3 варианта - через переметр метода init

```
class GuessingBinary {
    private int min;
    private int max;

    public void init(int min, int max){
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public int guessNum() {
        //  .....
    }
}
```

но тут очевидный недостаток - любой код может вызвать этот метод init (или забыть его вызвать) и переписать наши значения минимума и максимума. То есть этот класс становится использовать небезопасно, работа с таким классом черевата ошибками. Можно ли лучше? Да, можно, например, использовать конструктор

```
class GuessingBinary {
    private final int min;
    private final int max;

    public GuessingBinary(int min, int max){

        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public int guessNum() {
        //  .....
    }
}
```

Вроде стало лучше, теперь никто не перепишет наши минимумы и максимумы. Но возникает вопрос - а эти поля нам вообще здесь нужны? В чем вообще причина для добавления этих полей? Чтобы угадать число. Почему мы не можем эти поля передать как параметры а метод, который угадывает число? Вот так:

```
class GuessingBinary {
    public int guessNum(int min, int max) {
        //  .....
    }
}
```

А мы, оказывается, можем. И это не только избавит нас от состояния в классе, но и позволит использовать объект для разных минимумов и максимумов.

Теперь поглядите на ваш класс и на мой класс. Скажите, вы видите, что мой класс проще? Вы видите, что в моем классе сложнее допустить ошибку? Вы видите, что мой класс легче тестировать? Вы видите, что мой класс даже проще прочитать? Вот ваш метод - `public void guessing(String string)` - вы можете понять, что он делает по его сигнатуре? А по моему методу? `public int guessNum(int min, int max)`?

Как видите, ваша проблема в том, что вы

1. Усложняете там, где не надо усложнять
2. Добавляете состояние там, где оно не нужно
3. Не умеете разделять отвественности между классами
4. И походу не читали что я вам советовал в вашем предыдущем вопросе.

Comment: Возникает справедливый вопрос - а зачем тут вообще класс тогда?

Comment: а что тут должно быть?

Comment: Ну смотрите - класс без состояния с одним методом. Как минимум возникает вопрос - а нужны ли нам объекты этого класса, как максимум - а нужен ли сам класс?

Comment: Класс без состояния - это типичный сервис. Класс с одной ответсвенностью, и одним методом - почему бы нет? Этот метод другому классу не отдашь - так как тогда у другого класса появится на 1 ответственность больше, что нарушает S из SOLID

Comment: S из SOLID - очень скользкая тема. Шаг вверх, шаг вниз по уровням абстракции и карета превращается в тыкву. Вот вы предложили отказаться от состояния для данного класса. Ну ок, а где тогда будем его хранить? В классе повыше, на который, внезапно, прилетит дополнительная ответственность, которую снова начнем кромсать, превращая код в усладу для глаз Егора Бугаенко?

Comment: SOLID становится скользкой темой, когда ее начинают воспринимать как правило и пихать везде без причин. Повторюсь, принципы - это всего лишь рекомендации. Вы не обязаны им следовать, если знаете, что делаете. В моем ответе я показал ход моих мыслей, а не единственно верное решение. Если бы в программировании существовало единственно верное решение, его бы давно автоматизировали и мы бы лишились работы. Однако, мой посыл был в том, что если ты пишешь код, то у тебя должны быть основания писать именно такой код и именно так.

Comment: Что касается состояния, то классу, который ответственен за угадывание, не должно быть интересно, кто и как хранит состояние. Его можно и в отдельном классе хранить, но я бы предпочел хранить его в локальных переменных метода start класса игры, так как это состояние используется только там.

Answer (score 0):

Все верно в предыдущем ответе. Помимо этого , на мой взгляд, стоит немного подправить код в классе GuessingBinary :

```
public class GuessingBinary {

    private int min, max;
    private int count;
    private int guessedNum;

    public GuessingBinary (int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        count = 1;
        guessedNum = max / 2;
    }

    public int getGuessedNum() {
        return guessedNum;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public boolean guessing(String string) {
        switch (string) {
            case "y": return true;
            case "<": max = guessedNum; break;
            case ">": min = guessedNum; break;
        }
        guessedNum = ((max - min) / 2) + min;
        count++;
        return false;
    }

}
```

А в классе измените данный фрагмент кода так :

```
GuessingBinary guessingBinary = new GuessingBinary(min, max);

while (!guessingBinary.guessing(scanner.next())) {
    System.out.println("Attempt: " + guessingBinary.getCount());
    System.out.println("Your num is: " + guessingBinary.getGuessedNum());
    System.out.print(":");

}
```

Ваш метод guessing ничего не возвращает, поэтому вам нужна дополнительная переменная. Мало того, переменной guessedNum достаточно, half также не нужна